# PHP Array sort by string date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array that looks like this

```
array(24) { ["#HiddenId"]=> string(24) "2013-11-08T11:59:54.378Z"] }
```

It has multiple ids/dates but I want to sort it by date (most recent)

I know how to do this for this format, "01/01/2014" however I Believe it is easier to work with this format, but I'm unsure of how to implement.

This is the code I have for format "01/01/2014"

```
uasort($fileList, "my_sort");

function my_sort($a,$b)
{
    $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $a);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $b);
    return $date1 < $date2;
}
```

I need to do this function similar but for the other format shown above.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Am I missing something or can this be done with a simple arsort($yourArray)  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
usort($yourArray,"strcmp");
```

"Big-endian" formats like `Y-m-d H:i:s` sort lexicographically.

Comment: How can I reference "hiddenId" without hardcoding like you have?

Comment: Isn't that part of your array structure? Don't you know the key of the date?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice answer, but wouldn't `rsort` work in the same way, while being simpler to use?

Comment: Well I need to sort the array by dates only, why do I need to reference the key values?

Comment: Because... you need to tell it where your date is?

Comment: Ok and if I have 100+ ids with dates, How can i sort all, I need to hard code each id like you have done?

Comment: why not just sort($yourArray)?